# How to log failed Asset detail in BCC during data import

Tags: logging, import, importerror, atg, bcc

I am importing csv files into ATG BCC manuallly.While import some assets failed due to data issue.For example category does not import due to missing child products.In BCC import popup it is showing message like 1 out of 44 item is missing.But it does not provide the id of the missing item.For larger data imports it is difficult to find out the failed repository ids in source data.

I tried to enabled the logs of /atg/web/assetmanager/transfer/ImportAsset but no help.
Is there any component in BCC where I can enable the logs and see the failed assets detail (in above example missing product ids for failed category)??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ATG are you having this problem with? I've just created a sample import file with some folders that does not exist and imported it. It reported that 2 items could not be imported and when I scrolled to the column in question it highlighted the missing folders. This is the case in ATG 9.x

[image: ATG BCC Import Errors]

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.I am using ATG 10.2.It just show the message 1 item missing like this.Not the id of the missing item.